# Replace tag in an expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

From a variable containing tags layout as `<img>`
I want to replace all the image tags and content by the same tag concatenated with `<br />`

for example:

`<img src="mon image" style="width:80px; float: right;">`

replaced by

`<img src="mon image" style="width:80px; float: right;"> <br />`

I succed to replace the `img` tag with a character but not like I want

Comment: Fyi: img tags always end with a closing slash `right;" />` else will fail validation...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to replace an <a> with respective <img>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449759/regular-expression-to-replace-an-a-with-respective-img). See also bobince's answer to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732454/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this regular expression:

```
$string = '<img src="mon image" style="width:80px; float: right;">';
$pattern = "/(\<img\b[^>]*>)/";
$replacement = '${1}<br/>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Also  @LawrenceCherone has right your `IMG` should be like this:

```
<img src="mon image" style="width:80px; float: right;"/>
```

But the regular expression also works with that tag declaration.